# Problem with a double integral

Tags: numerical-integration

Why is the following integral not evaluated by Mathematica (ver. 11.3, Windows 10)

```
Integrate[1, {x, 2 - Sqrt[2], 1}, {y, 
  1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)], 
  1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)]}]
```

Edit: This is actually a double integral $\int_{2-\sqrt{2}}^{1} dx \int_{ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)}}^{ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)}} dy$.

Comment: What integral do you want to solve? Could you write it out or post a picture?

Comment: This integral is difficult to solve analytically, but simple numerically. Therefore, use NIntegrate instead of Integrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused as to what integral you want to be solved.

You need to write the integral function in a form like

```
(*integrand*)
eq = 1;
(*limits*)
limits = {x, 2 - Sqrt[2], 1};

result = Integrate[eq, limits]
```

So, I don't understand your question - are you trying to integrate it twice?

```
eq = 1;
limits = {y, 
   1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)], 
   1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)]};
result1 = Integrate[eq, limits]
limits2 = {x, 2 - Sqrt[2], 1};
NIntegrate[result1, limits2]
```

Comment: I have edited my question. What I wrote is actually a double integral.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Tomi's solution, define a two-dimensional [region](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region.html):

```
R = ImplicitRegion[x*(x-2)*(x*y*(x-2)*(y-1)+1)+1 <= 0 &&
                   2 - Sqrt[2] <= x <= 1,
                   {x, y}];
```

Numerical integration over regions is straightforward:

```
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, R]]
(*    0.339303    *)
```

You can of course also use your original parametrization of the region:

```
R0 = ImplicitRegion[2 - Sqrt[2] <= x <= 1 &&
       1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)] <= y <=
       1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 8 x - 4 x^3 + x^4)/((-2 + x)^2 x^2)],
       {x, y}];
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, R0]]
(*    0.339303    *)
```